# Better way to handle player turn checking in js function?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am making a JavaScript built version of the dice game, Pig. I have about 4 places in my code where I need to check for whose turn it is to determine what to calculate and display. Currently, I am using a switch case in all 4 places partially because I am just using integers 1 and 2 to determine if player 1 or 2. Is there a better way to handle this?

I would assume keeping the handling inside the methods makes the most sense, but especially since I have only two players, is an if/else more efficient? I find the switch case to be more readable.

```
c.hold = function(){
    if(m.gameIsWon){return;}
    console.log('holding your turn total!');
    switch(m.playerTurn){
        case 1:
            m.playerOneOverallTotal += m.playerOneTurnTotal;
            console.log(`your overall total is now ${m.playerOneOverallTotal}`);
            console.log(`moving onto ${m.playerTwo}'s turn`);
            m.playerOneTurnTotal = 0;
            m.playerTurn = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            m.playerTwoOverallTotal += m.playerTwoTurnTotal;
            console.log(`your overall total is now ${m.playerTwoOverallTotal}`);
            console.log(`moving onto ${m.playerOne}'s turn`);
            m.playerTwoTurnTotal = 0;
            m.playerTurn = 1;
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Something went wrong: ${m.playerTurn}`);
            break;
    }
    c.roll(m.playerTurn);
};
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for improvements for working code. ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: There is no difference between a `switch` and an `if/else if/else` block. At least, none that is going to matter to a game of Pig :). Also, the best way of figuring this out is to try both and test the results.

Comment: Okay thank you! Will probably just keep the switch/case.

Comment: The more important things is to use objects `var playerOne = {overallTotal: …, turnTotal: …}, playerTwo = {overallTotal: …, turnTotal: …};` instead of enumerating different property names. With two objects, you can determine the active one, and then have code operate on it - for the next round, just swap objects instead of duplicating code.